# Windows azure Conflict Error

Tags: api, rest, azure

I am currently creating one VM per cloud service(java REST API) , say if i gave 10 request parallely , nearly 7-8 get succeeded , rest 2-3 gets error msg like this :

```
ConflictError : Windows Azure is currently performing an operation on this hosted service that requires exclusive access.
ConflictError : The operation cannot be performed at this time because a conflicting operation is underway. Please retry later.
ConflictError : The specified DNS name is already taken.
```

At that instance , i delete that cloudservice/VM and re-create again. Is there any other workaround ?